# Why threading doesn't work in my Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I try to launch this code on my computer and threading doesn't work:

```
import threading


def infinite_loop():
    while 1 == 1:
        pass

def myname():
    print("chralabya")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=infinite_loop())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=myname())

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

When I execute this program `myname()` is never executed. Can someone can explain to me why threading doesn't work?

Comment: When i execute this program  myname() is never execute

Comment: Not the original mistake, but related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython

Comment: `myname` is not executed because you are calling `infinite_loop` yourself which never returns. So execution never reaches the line `t2 = threading.Thread(target=myname())`

Answer (score 1):

`target=inifinite_loop()` *calls your function* (note the `()`) and assigns the result (which never comes) to the `target` parameter. That's not what you want!

Instead, you want to pass *the function itself* to the `Thread` constructor:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=infinite_loop)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=myname)
```